# Check if a value exist from another list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

Hi I am trying  to check if the a value exist from lost A in list B and based on my logic a method need to execute.

SPListItemCollection PersonalCalendar_items = spWeb.Lists["PersonalCalendar"].Items;

SPListItem NewPersonalCalendar_Item = PersonalCalendar_items.Add();

```
                    if (NewPersonalCalendar_Item["OldID"] ==null)
                    {
                        AddEventToCalendar(spWeb, LearningCalendar_Item, PersonalCalendar_items, NewPersonalCalendar_Item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool iExists = false;

                        foreach (SPListItem PersonalCalendaritem in PersonalCalendar_items)
                        {
                            //string one = LearningCalendar_Item["ID"].ToString();
                            //string two = PersonalCalendaritem["OldID"].ToString();

                            if (PersonalCalendaritem["Title"].ToString() == LearningCalendar_Item["Title"].ToString() || PersonalCalendaritem["Start Time"] == LearningCalendar_Item["Title"])
                            {
                                iExists = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (iExists != true)
                        {
                            Context.Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url.ToString() + "/Pages/already-enroll.aspx");

                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to use the caml query to check if the item exists. Try changing your else branch to this:

```
    bool iExists = false;
    string queryString = @"<Query>
         <Where>
          <And>
           <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Title' />
            <Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value>
           </Eq>
           <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Start_x0020_Time' />
            <Value Type='DateTime'>{1}</Value>  
           </Eq>
          </And>
         </Where>
        </Query>";

    SPList list = spWeb.Lists["PersonalCalendar"];
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Query = string.Format(queryString, LearningCalendar_Item["Title"].ToString(), LearningCalendar_Item["YourDateColumn"]);
    SPListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(query);
    if (listItems.Count != 0)
    {
        iExists = true;     
    }

    if (iExists != true)
    {
        Context.Response.Redirect(SPContext.Current.Web.Url.ToString() + "/Pages/already-enroll.aspx");
    }
```

In your example you compared both values with the Title field, so I guess that should be changed (since one of the columns has name "Start Time" it should probably be compared with some DateTime variable). You should replace the `LearningCalendar_Item["YourDateColumn"]` in my example with your appropriate variable.